# How to select * plus another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select all values from one table, then select the output of a function that is run of just one of those columns, and display all of that as my SQL query output. (My goal in doing this is to create a usable WKT output from the Geometry column, and have it in the query results, so I can run a single cx_Oracle cursor over all of it and pull out the parts that I need.)

Here's what I'm trying:

```
Select *, Sdo_Util.To_Wktgeometry(Poly.Geometry)
From Whse_Forest_Vegetation.Rslt_Forest_Cover_Poly Poly
```

But it's not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean in this context? Are there error messages? Has your computer melted into a puddle on your desk? Has a portal between the worlds opened through which hordes of demons have invaded the earthly plane? Other? Please edit your question and include additional info. Thanks.

Comment: Yes @BobJarvis , it was the portal between worlds + demons. One of them had a T-shirt on that said:

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Luckily I was able to slam the portal shut by employing the suggestion below..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to put the table_name in front of the *.

i.e.

```
Select Poly.*,
```

Comment: That's it! I knew it would be something simple like that...

Comment: So the proper SQL for what I'm trying to do is:    

`Select Poly.*,Sdo_Util.To_Wktgeometry(Poly.Geometry)`
`From Whse_Forest_Vegetation.Rslt_Forest_Cover_Poly Poly`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to put some prefix or the table name on it, could be something like this :

```
“SELECT sample.*, (sample.price) + 500 FROM tbl.sample”
```